Redirect all URLs in WordPress and Permalink to by country to subdomain
I have a WP question hoping someone can point me in right direction.
I need to redirect my store customers to a specific country subdomain for all pages, posts, and products. The main domain and subdomain have the same content, so I only need to change the URL.
For Example:
www.example.com main page
www.example.com/page1   , www.example.com/product1
For US visitor:
us.example.com main page
us.example.com/page1   , us.example.com/product1
For UK visitor:
uk.example.com main page
uk.example.com/page1   , uk.example.com/product1
Thank you.

you can do this with the help of the polylang plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

You can try to check the visitor country via the geojs.io, and then build the logic for redirecting.
See the JS code below:
geoTargeting();

  function geoTargeting() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch('https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
        const currentHostname = window.location.hostname;
        const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
        let newUrl;
        if (data.country === 'US') { // Check if country US
          const subdomain = 'us';
          newUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + subdomain + '.' + currentHostname + currentPath;
          window.open(newUrl); // Redirect
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }

      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        resolve(false);
      });

    });
  }

